# Regular expression to match strings in ""

Tags: regex

I have this `\"([^"]*)\"`
and on data `"""Storno ISP""- ""Nesprávne nastavená modulácia KZ (G.DMT/G.992.1B), potrebné nastaviť adsl2+ (G.992.5B)""" "Fast" "Battery" "JNAKA"`.

I would like to match only "Fast" "Battery" "JNAKA".
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You may  require no double quotes on each side:

```
(?<!")"([^"]+)"(?!")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GBXFSI/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<!")` - no `"` immediately on the left is allowed
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?!")` - no `"` immediately on the right is allowed.

Comment: Can you help me more I have `(?<!")"([^"]+)"(?!")|""([^"]*)""` but need match also "Wo PM" "Core" [link](https://regex101.com/r/eN9cP8/8)

Comment: @Coolman Maybe you need `"(?![\s-]+")([^"]+)"`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN9cP8/10).

Comment: `"(?![\s-]+")([^"]+)"` is good but need also match "WO PPM"  "Core" in "WO PPM"Core" is possible?

Comment: @Coolman  I do not think so. There is no way to know where the value ends/starts.